# Java / "Advanced" Checking

Tags: java, slick2d

I am trying to make a program where I can't find a solution for this:

I want to check if position_x is 0 or 20 or 40 or 60 or 80 or 100 or 120... until 1280 (always plus 20).

I hope you can help me further,

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the modulus here, e.g.

```
if (position_x % 20 == 0 && position_x >=0 && position_x <= 1280) {
    System.out.println("position_x is a multiple of 20 and within range.");
}
else {
    System.out.println("position_x is out of range or not a multiple of 20.");
}
```

Comment: @Whosayin20 Your comment got cutoff.

Comment: This Code worked for me now, changed some little things in my program. Thank you so much!